# Variable length look-behind

Tags: regex, perl

Is there any elegant solution to build a variable length look-behind regex such as this one ?

```
/(?<=eat_(apple|pear|orange)_)today|yesterday/g;
```

It seems Perl has a very impressive regex engine and variable length lookbehind would be very interesting. Is there a way to make it work or should I forget this bad idea ?

Comment: did you want to match only `today` or `yesterday` which comes just after to `eat_apple` or `eat_pear` or `eat_orange`

Comment: This is certainly possible today with `/((?<=eat_apple_)|(?<=eat_pear_)|(?<=eat_orange_))today|yesterday/g` But it’s much less elegant than what we might want. The REAL limitation is matchers with *s and +s or other wide range of lengths. My understanding is that .NET’s implementation works around this by reversing the pattern and the string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `\K` as a special case.

It's a variable length positive lookbehind assertion:

```
/eat_(?:apple|pear|orange)_\Ktoday|yesterday/g
```

Alternatively, you can list out your lookbehind assertions separately:

```
/(?:(?<=eat_apple_)|(?<=eat_pear_)|(?<=eat_orange_))today|yesterday/g
```

However, I would propose that it's going to be a rare problem that could potentially use that feature, but couldn't be rethought to use a combination of other more common regex features.

In other words, if you get stuck on a specific problem, feel free to share it here, and I'm sure someone can come up with a different (perhaps better) approach.

Comment: Nit: `\K` is not a variable-length lookbehind. It means "keep", and excludes whatever precedes it from being included in `$&` (the matched string). That said, `\K` can be used to emulate a variable-length positive lookbehind, so +1.

Answer (score 11):

How about:

```
(?:(?<=eat_apple_)|(?<=eat_pear_)|(?<=eat_orange_))(today|yesterday)
```

A little bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: +1 this is definitely a good workaround for a small finite list.

Comment: +1 And `(?<=eat_apple_|eat_pear_|eat_orange_)(today|yesterday)` (without parenthesized subpatterns) would not work in perl? Still fixed length: [see example](http://regex101.com/r/sT2bH5/2)

Comment: @Jonny5: No, there're not equal in length.

Answer (score 5):

Blog post found today, linked to me at #regex @ irc.freenode.org:

http://www.drregex.com/2019/02/variable-length-lookbehinds-actually.html

This article explains how to do a variable width look-behind in PCRE.

The solution would then be:

```
/(?=(?=(?'a'[\s\S]*))(?'b'eat_(?:apple|pear|orange)_(?=\k'a'\z)|(?<=(?=x^|(?&b))[\s\S])))today|yesterday/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/9DNpFj/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use look-ahead instead of look-behind:

```
/(?:eat_(apple|pear|orange)_)(?=today|yesterday)/g
```

and in general, there is an alternative way to describe things that naively seem to require look-behind.

Answer (score 3):

Perl v5.30 adds [experimental variable-width lookbehinds](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/03/use-a-variable-width-lookbehind-if-it-wont-match-more-than-255-characters/) in situations where the regex engine knows that the length will be 255 characters or less (so, no unbounded quantifiers, for example).

This now works:

```perl
use v5.30;
use experimental qw(vlb);

$_ = 'eat_apple_today';
say "Matched!" if /(?<=eat_(apple|pear|orange)_)today|yesterday/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution - reverse the string and use lookahead instead. It may look ugly having to write the pattern words in reverse but it's an option when everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:
Temporarily make whatever is variable in length fixed in length.

In this case:
Change all your 'eat_apple's, 'eat_pear's and 'eat_orange's to something like eat_fruit, and then run the expression you were thinking of with an acceptable fixed length look-behind. Even though it takes two passes and some memory, I find the code way easier to read, and it might be faster than some of these other solutions.