# Regex variable length lookbehind into wildcard

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have strings in the form of

```
[Identifier][Keyword][Number]Text
```

Where identifier is `\w*`, Keyword is one of `Button`, `Link`, or `Text`, Number is `[0-9]*` and text is the literal word `Text`. I am trying to match strings that don't fit this pattern.

Examples I would like matched:

- MyIdentifier
- MyIdentifierText
- MyIdentifierButton
- MyIdentifierButton1
- Button
- Button1
- Text

Examples I don't want matched:

- ButtonText
- MyIdentifierButtonText
- Button1Text
- MyIdentifierButton1Text
- TextText
- Text1Text

I have come up with this:

```
^\w*(?:(?<!Button)|(?<!Link)|(?<!Text))[0-9]*(?<!Text)$
```

That is correct except it does not match the following:

- Text
- MyIdentifierText

I know the issue is with the first lookbehind, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563891/variable-length-look-behind) and it didn't help, but that question also didn't have a wildcard before the lookbehind.

Comment: Just split a string with your matching pattern to get all non-matching parts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using this to search for lines in files using Visual Studio so manipulating the strings is not an option.

Comment: Visual Studio does not use PCRE, it uses .NET regex flavor. Do you have these strings  on separate lines? If yes, try `^(?!\w*(?:Button|Link|Text)[0-9]*Text$).*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad on the tag, apparently there isn't one for .NET regex (or at least I couldn't find it). I'm testing using a PCRE tool and the sample data is on separate lines for now. The actual strings are not necessarily on separate lines but are contained in HTML data attributes (data-myattribute="{string}"). I felt including that detail would clutter the question.

Comment: Using a PCRE testing tool won't help if the ultimate goal is to do this in VS.

Comment: Please provide exact sample data and exact expected output. I understand you are using a search and replace dialog.

Comment: If you want to remove all text not matching your pattern, it is much simpler in Notepad++.

Comment: Try `(\w*(?:Button|Link|Text)[0-9]*Text)|(?:(?!\w*(?:Button|Link|Text)[0-9]*Text)[\s\S\r])+` and replace with `$1\n`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QnFmqX/1).

Comment: Please leave feedbak if you need any more hints on it. It is not quite clear what you are doing.

Comment: Any feedback yet?