# PCRE Regex - Backreference not working inside lookahead or after pipe

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pcre, backreference

My regex query is the following ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6Lc2M/1)):

`(?'a'[~_])(?=(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)\k'a')|(?=(?=(?'b'[\s\S]*))(?'c'\k'a'(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)(?=\k'b'\z)|(?<=(?=x^|(?&c))[\s\S])))\k'a'`

The problem I'm facing is that backreferences to the named capture group `(?'a'~_)` fail to match in the part of the query on the right side of the main pipe:

`(?=(?=(?'b'[\s\S]*))(?'c'\k'a'(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)(?=\k'b'\z)|(?<=(?=x^|(?&c))[\s\S])))\k'a'`

They do however work on the part to the left of the pipe:

`(?'a'[~_])(?=(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)\k'a')`

The purpose of the query is to match *only* the surrounding delimiters of strings such as `~test~` or `_test_`, with a few additional criteria, which it does by first matching the opening delimiter with a lookahead ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CrwU8U/1)), and then using a [variable length lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563891/variable-length-look-behind) to match the closing delimiter ([demo with literals instead of backreferences](https://regex101.com/r/U4MkU8/1)).

While I am aware the query could be wildly simplified using `\K` or capture groups, neither are an option for me.

Comment: In regex ``(x)|\1`` right side of pipe starts execute only when left side fails. When right side fails capture1 is not set. So ``\1`` is never succeeds.

Comment: You could use this regex: ``(?'a'[~_])(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)(?'b'\k'a')`` First delimiter is captured by capturegroup 'a' and second - by capturegroup 'b'

Comment: @Michail while that would indeed be a lot easier, I unfortunately cannot use capture groups outside the query itself (edited question to mention this); it's necessary for the query to match the delimiters and only the delimiters.

Comment: Clarify please: in text ``_a_b_`` you need to match only first and second ``_`` or all three ``_``?

Comment: @Michail Ideally only the first and the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is great. You can just correct it a little.

```
(?'a'[~_])(?=
   (?'d'(?!\s)(?:(?!\k'a').)+(?<!\s)\k'a') |
   (?=(?'b'.*))(?'c'
      ^(?>\k'a'(?&d)|.)*\k'a'(?&d)(?=\k'b'\z) |
      (?<=(?=x^|(?&c)).)
   )
)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cyyQEJ/1)

But I think that the performance of such a regex will be low.

Comment: This looks absolutely perfect, thanks. Performance isn't an issue since I don't plan on parsing over-long files, and this is probably already better than what I had before.